# Ошибка при сортировке массива

Tags: java

Задача построена так:

> Задан массив положительных целых чисел. Преобразовать его таким образом чтобы сначала шли все четные а потом все нечетные.

Вот как-то так пытался это сделать

```
  Input: [3,1,2,4]
  Output: [2,4,3,1]

  public class ex2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {3, 2, 1, 4};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {

            if (arr[i - 1] % 2 == 1) {

                arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {

            if (arr[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                int tmp = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = tmp;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
}
```

Comment: Вы попробуйте разобраться, что происходит внутри ваших if-ов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arr[] = {3, 2, 1, 4};
int out[] = new int[arr.length];
int o=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
        out[o++]=arr[i];}}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
       out[o++]=arr[i];}}
```